# C++: delete strange behaviour

Tags: c++, dynamic

I have started doing some stuff with dynamic allocation in C++ but I had some problems.   Here's the code:

```
nrMare(char cifS[], char* startPos = new char())
{
    n = 0;
    int i;
    cif = startPos;
    printf("%p %i\n", cif, (cif - (char*)NULL) % 8);
    for(i = strlen(cifS) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        cif--;
        n++;
        cif = new(cif) char(cifS[i] - '0');
    }
}
~nrMare()
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        delete(cif);
        cif++;
    }
    n = 0;
    cif = 0;
}
```

nrMare is a class (it comes from bigNumber in Romanian :D) which is supposed to be able to contain the digits of a big number.

The problem is that the destructor (~nrMare) gives a weird error, when I make a variable nrMare something() on my computer, but it works for 116 digits long ones.

Do you have any suggestion or explainations?

EDIT: cif is a (char*) type

EDIT #2: n is the length of the number. I use the char pointer this way because I want to be able to add (like n++; cif--; cif = new(cif) char(number_to_add); -> this would add number_to_add in the left side of cif) and draw elements from both sides.

EDIT #3: this is gonna be a long one... Sorry for being such a bad explainer and thanks for your patience.here are some operators:

```
void operator-=(nrMare nr2)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i <= n && i <= nr2.n; i++)
        cif[n - i] -= nr2[nr2.n - i];
    for(i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if(cif[i] < 0)
        {
            cif[i] += 10;
            cif[i - 1]--;
        }
    }
    while(cif[0] == 0)
    {
        cif++;
        n--;
        //delete(cif - 1);
    }
}
int operator/=(int nr)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        cif[i + 1] += (cif[i] % nr) * 10;
        cif[i] = cif[i] / nr;
    }
    i = cif[n - 1] % nr;
    cif[n - 1] /= nr;
    while(cif[0] == 0)
    {
        cif++;
        n--;
        //delete(cif - 1);
    }
    return i; // the return value is this big number % nr
}

void operator*=(int cifTimes)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cif[i] *= cifTimes;
    }
    for(i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if(cif[i] > 9)
        {
            if(i != 0)
            {
                cif[i - 1]++;
                cif[i] %= 10;
            }
            else
            {
                n++;
                cif[0] %= 10;
                cif--;
                cif = new(cif) char(cif[0] = 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT #4: n = length of the number = number of digits = number of bytes. Weird error means it just crashes. I don't know how to find more about it. MinGW compiler asks Visual Studio (Visual C++) to debug it because it has some problems. This is for a problem, and somewhere (in the evaluator) it says "Killed by signal 6(SIGABRT)", if this helps.

EDIT #...: @Branko Dimitrijevic: I don't wanna be lazy... I want my own... I had this problem in more attempts to make something running. If I take out the destructor, it works just fine, just I guess then it would be a memory leak that way... I really want to find out why would this occur... and only for specific sizes and, i.e. **it doesn't crash on the first "delete", but on the 11'th in my case, that's why it's weird** .

Comment: it would be at least useful to know what types the involved variables are

Comment: Can you give a reduced example that compiles and exhibits the problem?

Comment: I thought the name was a reference to nightmare as way to describe the code for not using vectors, taking a `char[]` as a parameter and calculating offsets from a `NULL` `char *` :D

Comment: sorry, cif comes from digit and it's a (char*) variable

Comment: Good Lord. Pick up a C++ book, and read on pointers and arrays. There are much too many `new` here for you to be knowing what you are doing. In C++, `new` is *scarce*.

Comment: And how the constructor has been called. `new char()` looks very suspicious---why would one want to dynamically allocate a single `char`?

Comment: List your inputs, the error and types of n and cif

Comment: Er, that's placement new. That's not where you start with new! You are going to need to tell us what you actually want to do because this code is broken beyond all conceivable remedy.

Comment: Post the errors you're getting and post a complete program that exhibits those errors (the smallest complete program you can make that exhibits the errors).

Comment: "I use the char pointer this way because I want to be able to add (like n++; cif--; cif = new(cif) char(number_to_add); -> this would add number_to_add in the left side of cif) and draw elements from both sides." No, that's really not how it works at all.

Comment: On top of what others have said, **don't ever** just say "weird error". Describe what is going on as precisely as you can, and in as much detail as you can.

Comment: Also, what is "length of the number". Number of significant bits, number of decimal digits in a string representation of the number, number of hexadecimal digits, number of bytes, etc, etc...?

Comment: So, you are trying to implement a "big int", right? I think you should throw this whole piece of code away and start from scratch using `std::vector<char>` to store base-256 digits of the number. And please make it correct first, before attempting to "optimize" its performance. BTW, if this is not a homework and you actually need it in a real project, you'll probably be better-off simply reusing some of the existing big int libraries (Google is your friend).

Comment: Let's see if I can get your attention. You are using placement new. Don't. You are using placement new. Don't. You are using placement new. Don't. OK, got your attention. Now you should go and learn what placement new is.

Answer (score 3):

The `delete` can only work correctly on an address that is at the **beginning** of a **dynamically-allocated** block.

The `cif` will fail one or both of these conditions, leading to undefined behavior when the destructor calls `delete`, for following reasons:

- You assign `startPos` to `cif` and then modify it in a very strange way before calling the [placement new](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax). So even if `startPos` is a properly allocated block of dynamic memory, the `cif` **no longer points to the starting address** of it.
- If the caller passes an address of a stack-based variable to `startPos`, then you **no longer deal with dynamic memory at all**.

Not to mention that you call `new` and `delete` in a loop - what's up with that? There is also a fair chance for bombarding the memory unless you craft your input parameters in a very specific way. This whole block of code looks suspicious, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I use startPos just in the initialisation. Then I have a big number stored like cif[0] = first digit, cif[1] = second digit, ... , cif[n - 1] = last digit; if I would call nrMare("123456"), cif[0] would be 1 (not its' ascii value), cif[1] == 2 , ... cif[n - 1] == 6, and n is 6;

Comment: I use it this way because I want to add, substract , multiply...so 1234 - 1000 = 0234, and to remove the first 0 I would only have to do cif++; n--; (cif initially points at 0, and then it would point at 2)

Comment: @cristipiticul You are trying to explain _how_ are you doing (or rather, attempting to), not _what_ are you doing. Please provide a more high-level description of your end-goal.